# Wrong root on image_tag, include_tags, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my dev setup, generated routes are mysteriously pointing to my public www server.

[yields]

```
<script src="http://www.mysite.com//javascripts/prototype.js?1265304231" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://www.mysite.com//javascripts/effects.js?1265304231" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://www.mysite.com//javascripts/dragdrop.js?1265304231" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://www.mysite.com//javascripts/controls.js?1273647885" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://mysite.opzi.com//javascripts/application.js?1273611341" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where is this option set?  Can't find it for the life of me.

Comment: Please add the code that generates the path.

Answer (score 3):

One way this would happen is if you set `ActionController::Base.asset_host` to point to your public server in environment.rb.

Comment: Alex is most likely correct - is this in your `config/environment.rb` or in your `config/environment/development.rb`? You can read more about this in the Rails API for `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper`.

Comment: I think Alex has it, especially with the double slash between the root URL and path.

Answer (score 1):

Just since no one has provided a way to troubleshoot this:

The problem is likely an extra slash in one of your configs.  `asset_host` is prepended to all asset tags generated programmatically, so using ERB:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :defaults %>
```

will give you the equivalent of:

```
<%= "<link href='#{ActionController::Base.asset_host}/stylesheets/defaults.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />" %>
```

To check the contents of `asset_host` just print it out somewhere in one of your pages:

```
asset_host is set to: "<%= ActionController::Base.asset_host %>"
```

I would suspect you will get something back like `http://www.mysite.com/`.  The problem is the ending slash.  It should rather be set to `http://www.mysite.com`.  Now it is just a matter of tracking down the setting in your configs.  An easy way would just be to search for `http://www.mysite.com/` in your source to find the relevant setting mighty fast!

If you want to override it just in the current process, you can set `asset_host` to whatever you want:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = "http://www.mysite.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `config/environment.rb` and `config/environment/development.rb` files.

Look specifically for any `asset_host` tags. From guides.rubyonrails.org:

> asset_host provides a string that is prepended to all of the URL-generating helpers in AssetHelper. This is designed to allow moving all javascript, CSS, and image files to a separate asset host.

For more information, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Facebooker, it might be callback_url setting in facebooker.yml config file that is affecting ActionController::Base.asset_host value and corrupting your routes.